# Use Spring RestTemplate to return images and PDFs as Base64 strings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I currently try to extend the Spring RestTemplate with the purpose of having some standard methods for doing REST operations like GET and POST. As an example, I have made this method for making a GET operation:

```
class HttpClient extends RestTemplate {

    HttpClient() {
        super()
    }

    HttpHeaders headers = initialHeaders()

    ResponseEntity<String> get(String url) {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = this.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, getHttpEntity(), String.class)
        return response
    }

    private HttpEntity getHttpEntity() {
        return new HttpEntity(headers)
    }

}
```

This method works fine for getting text data like XML or JSON. But when I want to obtain image/PDF data, I currently use a separate method for obtaining the response as a byte array, which I can then convert to a Base64 encoded String. But is it possible to somehow make the RestTemplate convert all data of certain Mime-Types to Base64 encoded Strings, so that I can use the same method for varying response types?

Comment: You can create custom [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) and add it to the list of converters list of your RestTemplate instance. You should add it to the start (`.add(0, ....)`) to make sure your converter will preceed others

Answer (score 1):

```
ResponseEntity<Object> get(String url) {
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = this.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, getHttpEntity(), byte[].class)
```

it worked for me.
And don't forget HttpHeaders "Accept".